# How to make static React site and put it to IPFS

Tags: web3js, react, ipfs, frontend

I am using site build with Create React App and it all works fine when I run it on server. What I would like is to put it to IPFS and for that it needs to be a "generated static website" (no server side rendering), sometimes called also snapshot of website. I tried few tools like
https://github.com/stereobooster/react-snap  and https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-snapshot and they work fine for basic react site, but when I introduce redux for state management sites dont work anymore and JS used for connecting to metamask and making blockchain actions isnt working. Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Use [create-eth-app](https://github.com/paulrberg/create-eth-app). The boilerplate you get includes a script for deploying to IPFS

Comment: thnx for suggestion, will check it out.